# Point transposition on a circle

Tags: geometry

If you have a random point on a circle of a certain diameter how do you transpose that point to be in the same place on a circle with a smaller diameter

Comment: do we know anything about the locations of the circles

Comment: By the linear map that sends one circle onto the other.

Comment: Scale the distance from the center by the ratio of the diameters.  The angle from the center is the same.